# Code snippet in the Atom text editor returns the error: unexpected newline

Tags: atom-editor, code-snippets

I've been trying to add my first snippet in the Atom text editor and I keep getting the error that there's an unexpected newline:

```
'.source.js':
 'Console log':
   'prefix': 'log'
     'body': 'console.log($1)'

  'Constructor':
    'prefix': 'rcon'
     'body':"""
          constructor(props){
             super(props);

             this.state = {$1};
          }
        """

    'Component':
       'prefix': 'rcom'
       'body': """
           class $1 extends Component {
             render(){
               return(
                  <div>
                     $2
                  </div>
               );
             }
          }
        """
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Normally, an editor alone does not show such error messages

Answer (score 0):

CoffeeScript (and thus CSON) is an indentation-sensitive language, so you need to make sure your code uses correct indentation. Tools like [CoffeeLint](http://www.coffeelint.org/#usage) will highlight indentation errors in your code (there's also an [Atom package](https://atom.io/packages/linter-coffeelint) for it)

The first indentation error is in line 4: the `body` key is supposed to be on the indentation level as `prefix`. The same goes for each of the three snippets, they should be on the same indentation level as well.

The full CSON should look like this:

```
'.source.js':
  'Console log':
    'prefix': 'log'
    'body': 'console.log($1)$0'
  'Constructor':
    'prefix': 'rcon'
    'body': """
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {$1};
        }$0
    """
  'Component':
    'prefix': 'rcom'
    'body': """
        class $1 extends Component {
            render(){
                return(
                    <div>
                        $2
                    </div>
                );
            }
        }$0
    """
```

PS: You can also use JSON for your snippets, if you dislike CSON.

Comment: I don't understand please give me a solution

Comment: I've added a valid version of your snippets, but you should try and understand how  you can solve these problems yourself in the future.